# SQL INNER JOIN showing specific values

Tags: sql, mariadb

I need to write a query which must include use of INNER JOIN, but did not manage to write it correctly.

In PhpMyAdmin, I created a database with two related tables of users:

Table #1 is called "Usertype" and has two columns:

1.typnum (auto increment)

2.typdsc - which has three types of values: Inactive, Guest and Webmaster

Table #2 is called "Users" and has five columns:

1. usrnum
2. usrlogin
3. usrpassword
4. usrrealname
5. usrtyp (the foreign key I connected with typnum)

What I need to show is the following records of Guests and Webmasters: usrlogin, usrpassword, usrrealname and the name of their types (while using Inner Join for the last one).
In other words, I need to show records which are NOT 'Inactive', show what their types are instead and the rest of their values EXCEPT usrnum

This is the query I tried to write for this:

```
SELECT users.usrlogin,users.usrpassword,users.usrrealname AND user.usrtyp
FROM users 
WHERE usrtyp NOT IN 'Inavctive' AND INNER JOIN userstypes ON users.usrtyp = userstypes.typnum
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you provide any sample data and your desired result? I do not understand ' show what their types are instead and the rest of their values EXCEPT usrnum'

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I had complications translating it to English. And although someone already posted an answer for me, thank you for your reply!

Comment: The components of a `SELECT` statements have a strict order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT u.usrlogin, u.usrpassword, u.usrrealname, ut.typdsc 
FROM users u INNER JOIN userstypes ut
ON u.usrtyp = ut.typnum
WHERE ut.typdsc <> 'Inactive'
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! It does show only the columns I need, but it also still shows for me the user I marked as 'Inactive'. Is there another way to remove that line?

Comment: The problem was due to the wrong `string`. The `string` you provided in the question is `'Inavctive'`, probably it must be `'Inactive'`. I also updated the answer.

Comment: Yes it worked! Sorry for my typo, but thank you SO SO MUCH for your fast replies!

Answer (score 0):

order matters in sql where is last.  Also remove the random AND

```
SELECT users.usrlogin,users.usrpassword,users.usrrealname, userstypes.usrtyp
FROM users 
INNER JOIN userstypes ON users.usrtyp = userstypes.typnum
WHERE usrtyp NOT IN ('Inavctive')
```